# g++, creating static library for distribution

Tags: c++, boost, g++, static-libraries

I have code that compiles well using the following makefile

```
all: sample

sample: sample.o mylib.o
    g++ -Wall -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -o sample -L/usr/lib sample.o mylib.o -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams -lz -I /usr/include/boost 

sample.o: sample.cpp
    g++ -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -I /usr/include/boost -c -o sample.o sample.cpp

mylib.o: mylib.cc mylib.h
    g++ -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -I /usr/include/boost -c -o mylib.o mylib.cc
```

Now, mylib.cc and mylib.h contains a lot of useful code that I would like to share. However, it depends on Boost which my target audience might not have or know how to install properly.

Is there a way for me to distribute a mylib.o that is static with a mylib.h that my end user can just compile into their own code without needing to install Boost?

ADDITIONAL CLARIFICATION: mylib.h does not contain any BOOST headers, but mylib.cc DOES contain boost headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to create a "boost-free" header, you can do that.

As soon, as you have any references to boost stuff within the header (which you need to redistribute), you can't.

If your cc file uses boost classes which are not header-only, you need to distribute those files, too - either in sourcecode, or within an object-file - which however can lead to strange behavior, if an user uses another version of the boost library and tries to instantiate classes, which are already defined within your object files.

One possible solution would be to find out, which cc-files of boost are required and compile them within a different namespace, e.g. using `-Dboost=my_boost`:

```
g++ -Dboost=my_boost <put additional compiler options here> my_boost_file.cc -c my_boost_file.o
```

You also should compile your own object file with that define.

Finally create an archive containing all the required object files;

```
ar rvs my_archive.a mylib.o my_boost_file.o
```

Comment: Not can't, rather it is very annoyingly difficult, useless and unconventional. In addition to possibly conflicting with tge user being able to use a copy of boost installed on his system or his own copy.

Comment: So, I was able to completely erradicate Boost from my header. But the .cc file associated with the header uses Boost. Is there a way for me to do this then?

Comment: As long as you use the header-only parts of boost (most of boost is header-only), yes, you should be able to distribute the library and your header.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am using serialization which is not header-only.

Comment: You still can compile it statically, but this may lead to conflicts, if the user uses boost, too. You can work around that by putting boost into your own namespace (e.g. compiling your file(s) as well as the boost .cc-files with `-Dboost=myboost`). This is a little bit unconventional, but at least a possible workaround...

Comment: I forgot something: You need to create an archive file (myfile.a), the object file won't be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @Mark, can you edit your answer with more specifics about how I would be able to compile this statically?

Comment: @Mark, thanks for the edit, but a couple things still aren't clear to me. You are saying I need to compile the Boost libraries themselves and also distribute them. For boost_serialization for instance, how would I go about doing that? What is my_boost_file.cc in the above?

Comment: I'm currently at my windows machine where I don't have boost installed and I won't reach my linux account until the 8th. Just try to compile a simple program that uses your mylib.h which uses the boost stuff from a different namespace. Call every function once in your main and build it without using -lboost. You'll most probably get unresolved externals. Search for these unresolved externals in the boost source tree and rebuild them in the new namespace.

This is still very 'hacky', it would be much better to provide the sourcecode for your library.

Answer (score 1):

If `mylib.h` includes Boost header files, those will need to be present in some form on the developer's system.  At a minimum, you would have to ship that part of Boost with your code.

However, if you can create a smaller header file that exposes just the pieces of your library and does not include nor reference anything in Boost, then you can.  Most of Boost is header-only (the required Boost code will be compiled into your library already).

Comment: Just clarified my original question, mylib.h does NOT contain any Boost headers, but the implementations, in mylib.cc does use boost and there are boost headers in mylib.cc

Comment: Then as long as the pieces of Boost you are using are header-only (that is, you don't have to link to any Boost libraries) then you are already set.

Comment: Unfortunately no, serialization is one of the compiled boost libraries, guess i am out of luck.